# Is there a way to show all data with matching fields in sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I got 2 tables

cbmsH

```
hh_id   | name  | age
9437556 | John  | 40
9886016 | Doe   | 35
```

cbms

```
hh_id   | name  | age
9437556 | Peter | 41
9886016 | Tony  | 35
9886016 | Thor  | 32
9886016 | Loki  | 30
```

And I'm expecting like this

```
hh_id   | name  | age
9437556 | John  | 40
9437556 | Peter | 41
____________________________

hh_id   | name  | age
9886016 | Doe   | 35
9886016 | Tony  | 35
9886016 | Thor  | 32
9886016 | Loki  | 30
____________________________
```

ive tried this

```
SELECT cbmsh.hh_id AS head_hhid, cbmsh.barangay AS head_barangay, cbmsh.memno AS head_memno,cbmsh.last_name AS head_last ,cbmsh.first_name AS head_first ,cbmsh.mid_name AS head_mid,cbmsh.relationship,cbmsh.sex AS head_sex,cbmsh.birthdate AS head_birthdate,cbmsh.age AS head_age,cbmsh.occupation AS head_occupation,cbmsh.pwd_ind, cbms.hh_id AS mem_hhid, cbms.barangay, cbms.memno,cbms.last_name AS mem_last,cbms.first_name AS mem_first,cbms.mid_name AS mem_mid,cbms.relationship AS mem_relationship,cbms.sex AS mem_sex,cbms.birthdate AS mem_birthdate,cbms.age AS mem_age,cbms.occupation AS mem_occupation,cbms.pwd_ind
FROM cbmsh, cbms
WHERE cbmsh.hh_id = cbms.hh_id
GROUP BY head_hhid
```

But it's showing only 1 data like this. Instead of showing the all the records with same hh_id

```
hh_id   | name  | age
9886016 | Doe   | 35
9886016 | Tony  | 35
```

Can someone help me this? Any help will be appreciated! Good day everyone

Comment: That's what `GROUP BY` does, it combines all the records with the same `hh_id` into a single row in the results.

Comment: Maybe you meant `ORDER BY` so that all the rows with the same `hh_id` would be together sequentially.

Comment: You can't get that result with the query you show. First, it's missing lots of columns. Second, you won't get two rows with `hh_id = 9886016`.

Comment: The results you want don't look like a `JOIN`, they look like `UNION`.

Comment: That's what i want to achieve to get the all the rows with same hh_id. I've tried using ORDER BY but it's not working. There is a lot of columns in there. I just post with the important one's to show my point. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. You don't want to `JOIN` the tables, you want to `UNION` them. `JOIN` is for combining related rows of the two tables into a single row in the results. But you want to keep all the rows separate.
2. You don't want `GROUP BY`, which is used for aggregating rows with the same value of a column into a single row (e.g. when counting or summing across rows). If you want to keep the rows separate but together, you use `ORDER BY`.

So the query should be

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT hh_id, name, age
    FROM cbmsh
    UNION
    SELECT hh_id, name, age
    FROM cbms
) x
ORDER BY hh_id
```